# How to auto execute commands after opening a file in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to do something like this: auto execute commands `(split-window-right)`  `(follow-mode)`    `(visual-line-mode)` after opening a file.

Comment: Any file? a specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to write your own "open file" command:

```
(defun my-find-file ()
  "Like `find-file', but splits screen and enables Follow Mode."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively #'find-file)
  (follow-delete-other-windows-and-split)
  (visual-line-mode 1))
```

You can bind it to `C-x C-f`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") #'my-find-file)
```

I've used `follow-delete-other-windows-and-split` rather than `split-window-right` and `follow-mode` and the latter doesn't work that well when a frame already contains multiple windows.

Also, you might consider enabling `visual-line-mode` using other mechanisms like mode-specific hooks or `global-visual-line-mode`.

Comment: `(global-set-key [remap find-file] #'my-find-file)` would remap all global keybindings for `find-file`, which I think is generally a preferable approach to this sort of thing, unless you particularly want to retain some original bindings.